# Powershell not properly reading negative numbers

Tags: powershell

I have a program and I'm simply trying to check for a negative number but it is not liking it. Have any tips?

```
$numbers = @(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9)
$number = Read-Host "Please input a number: " 
if ($number -le 0)
    {
        Write-Output "Thanks for using the program! Exitting now..."
        $finished = 1
    }
    elseif ($number -notin $numbers)
    {
        Write-Error "Input must be numeric"
        continue
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Good number!"
    }
```

Comment: You are reading into `$number` but checking `$radius`?

Comment: As Etan Reisner said you're not checking $number.

Comment: Sorry look at it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Read-Host` produces `[string]` output, so you're actually doing a string comparison, and not getting the result you expect.  Cast `$number` to `[int]` to do a mathematical comparison:

```
if ([int]$number -le 0)
```