# PowerShell Implicit Type Conversions - does it happen? Is it safe?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a handle on documentation/evidence around when `PowerShell` does conversions, and when a user needs to be explicit about what they want. A somewhat related question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57956576/15243610), has a broken link that possibly explained scenarios that the type would be adjusted. There are plenty of instances of similar problems though (namely, comparing a `string` to an `int`) - for example when you [get a number via `Read-Host`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375630/powershell-not-properly-reading-negative-numbers), you're actually getting a string.

Specifically though I've found that certain mechanisms seem to handle a string representation of the number fine - but I want to understand if that is truly because they're handling it as a number, or if the output is correct in appearance, but wrong under the hood. Here's a specific example though, so the question is about `Measure-Object` and how it handles calculating the `Sum` of a string property.

```
PS > $Example = Import-Csv .\Example.csv
PS > $Example

Procedure_Code : 123456789
CPT_Code       : J3490
Modifier       :
Service_Date   : 02/01/2020
Revenue_Code   : 259
Units          : -100.00
Amount         : 55.00

Procedure_Code : 123456789
CPT_Code       : J3490
Modifier       :
Service_Date   : 02/02/2020
Revenue_Code   : 259
Units          : 100.00
Amount         : 55.00

PS > [Math]::Sign($Example[0].Units)
-1

PS > $Example | Measure-Object Amount -Sum

Count             : 2
Sum               : 110
Property          : Amount

PS > $Example | ForEach-Object { $Sum = $Sum + $_.Amount} ; Write-Host "$($Sum)"
55.0055.00  #Plus sign concatenates strings

PS > $Example | ForEach-Object { $Sum = $Sum + [int]$_.Amount} ; Write-Host "$($Sum)"
110  #Expected result if casting the string into an integer type before adding
```

So basically it seems like [`[Math]::Sign()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=net-5.0) works (even though it doesn't accept strings as far as I can tell), and `Measure-Object` is smarter about strings than a simple plus sign. But is `Measure-Object` casting my string into an `[int]`? If I use an example with decimals, the answer is more precise, so maybe it is a `[single]`?

What is `Measure-Object` doing to get the right answer, and when shouldn't I trust it?

Comment: In the case of `Measure-Object`, it deliberately takes care of converting input values that are strings to a numerical type when you specify `-Sum` or `-Average` (because it makes no sense to attempt to calculate those over a set of strings), in other words: the behavior is cmdlet-specific. The `[Math]::Sign()` example on the other hand is indeed a case of PowerShell implicitly converting the string value you passed to the method to a number, because no better parameter mapping exists

Comment: Got it. Cmdlet-specific makes sense and confirms the being deliberate and explicit makes the most sense for most scenarios. It looks like `Measure-Object` is converting to a `double`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) is a special case, because it is that cmdlet's *specific logic* that performs automatic type conversion, as opposed to PowerShell's own, *general* automatic conversions that happen in the context of using *operators* such as `+`, passing *arguments to commands*, calling *.NET methods* such as `[Math]::Sign()`, and using values *as conditionals*.

As [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69652125/45375) hints at, `Measure-Object` calls the same code that PowerShell's general automatic type conversions use; these are discussed below.

---

##### Automatic type conversions in PowerShell:

In general, **PowerShell *always* attempts *automatic* type conversion** - and a pitfall to those familiar with C# is that even an *explicit cast* (e.g. `[double] '1.2'`) may not be honored if the target type is ultimately a different one.<sup>[1]</sup>

**Supported conversions**:

- In addition to supporting .NET's type conversions, PowerShell implements a few **built-in custom conversions** and supports **user-defined conversions** by way of custom conversion classes and attribute classes; also, it **implicitly tries to call single-parameter target-type *constructors*** and - **for *string* input - a target type's static `::Parse()` method**, if present; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375) for details.

**To-number conversion and culture-sensitivity when converting to and from *strings***:

- Typically, PowerShell uses ***culture-invariant* conversion**, so that, for instance, only `.` is recognized as the decimal mark in "number strings" that represent floating-point numbers.
- String-to-number conversion, including how specific numeric data types are chosen, is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41091259/45375).
- To-string conversion (including from numbers) is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

**Automatic type conversions by context**:

- **Operands** (operator arguments):

  - *Some* operators, such as `-replace` and `-match`, operate on *strings only*, in which case the operand(s) are invariably converted to strings (which always succeeds):

    - `42 -replace 2, '!'` yields `'4!'`: both `42` and `2` were implicitly converted to strings.
  - Others, such as `-` and `\`, operate on *numbers only*, in which case the operand(s) are invariably converted to numbers (which may fail):

    - `'10' - '2'` yields `8`, an `[int]`
  - Yet others, such as `+` and `*`, can operate on *either* strings *or* numbers, and it is the *type of the LHS* that determines the operation type:

    - `'10' + 2` yields `'102'`, the *concatenation* of string `'10'` with the to-string conversion of number `2`.
    - By contrast, `10 + '2'` yields `12`, the *addition* of the number `10` and the to-number conversion of string `'2'`.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49755443/45375) for more information.
- ***Command* arguments**:

  - If the target parameter has a *specific type* (other than `[object]` or `[psobject]`), PowerShell will attempt conversion.
  - Otherwise, for *literal* arguments, the type is *inferred* from the literal representation; e.g. `42` is passed as an `[int]`, and `'42'` as a `[string]`.
- **Values serving as *conditionals***, such as in `if` statements:

  - A conditional must by definition be a *Boolean* (type `[bool]`), and PowerShell automatically converts a value of any type to `[bool]`, using the rules described in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
- ***Method* arguments**:

Automatic type conversion for .NET-method arguments can be tricky, because *multiple overloads* may have to be considered, and - if the argument's aren't of the expected type - PowerShell has to find the *best* overload based on supported type conversions - and it may not be obvious which one is chosen.

Executing `[Math]::Sign` (calling this *as-is, without `()`*) reveals 8(!) different overloads, for various numeric types.

More insidiously, **the introduction of additional .NET-method overloads in future .NET versions *can break existing PowerShell code***, if a new overload *then* happens to be the best match in a given invocation.

A high-profile example is the `[string]` type's `Split()` method - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).

Therefore, **for long-term code stability**:

- **Avoid .NET methods in favor of PowerShell-native commands, if possible**.
- **Otherwise**, if type conversion is necessary, ***use casts*** (e.g. `[Math]::Sign([int] '-42')`) to guide method-overload resolution to avoid ambiguity.

---

<sup>[1] E.g., the explicit `[double]` is quietly converted to an `[int]` in the following statement: `& { param([int] $i) $i } ([double] '1.2')`. Also, casts to .NET *interfaces* generally have no effect in PowerShell - except to guide overload resolution in .NET method calls.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the be-all and end-all answer, but it works for what I was curious about. For a lot of 'quick script' scenarios where you might use something like `Measure-Object` - you'll probably get the correct answers you're looking for, albeit maybe slower than other methods.

[`Measure-Object`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Measure-Object.cs) specifically seems to use `[double]` for `Sum`, `Average`, and `StandardDeviation` and will indeed throw an error if one of the string values from a CSV Object can't be converted.

I'm still a little surprised that `[Math]::Sign()` works at all with strings, but seemingly glad it does

```cs
            if (_measureAverage || _measureSum || _measureStandardDeviation)
            {
                double numValue = 0.0;
                if (!LanguagePrimitives.TryConvertTo(objValue, out numValue))
                {
                    _nonNumericError = true;
                    ErrorRecord errorRecord = new(
                        PSTraceSource.NewInvalidOperationException(MeasureObjectStrings.NonNumericInputObject, objValue),
                        "NonNumericInputObject",
                        ErrorCategory.InvalidType,
                        objValue);
                    WriteError(errorRecord);
                    return;
                }

                AnalyzeNumber(numValue, stat);
            }
```