# Powershell -eq operator

Tags: powershell, comparison, operators

Why does the expression `"1" -eq 1` comes TRUE in powershell ? The first one is of string type and the second one is of integer type why is it treating them as equal.

Comment: PowerShell tries to be helpful by converting the LHS operand to the RHS operand type, before executing any expression.

Comment: don't spam tags. Version-specific tags are only for issues that occur in that specific version

Comment: @phuclv i am sorry I am new here I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala thankyou sir for answering the question it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called implicit type conversion.

Powershell automatically perform a type conversion when a value of one type is used in a context that requires a different type.

> A type conversion is performed when a value of one type is used in a
> context that requires a different type. If such a conversion happens
> automatically it is known as implicit conversion. (A common example of
> this is with some operators that need to convert one or more of the
> values designated by their operands.) Implicit conversion is permitted
> provided the sense of the source value is preserved, such as no loss
> of precision of a number when it is converted.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06)

In addition to the official documentation, here is an excellent answer by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) here with some additional examples and references:  [PowerShell Implicit Type Conversions - does it happen? Is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653097/934946)